# AdonisJS - Cannot update unique field

Tags: sql, node.js, validation, adonis.js

AdonisJS is a Laravelish framework for Node.js, but even following Laravel solutions, I didn't work.

I have some `rules` setting two field as `unique`, but when updating it, it either fails accusing of having an existing in the database or it allows me to duplicate.

These are the rules:

```
get rules() {
    return {
      name: 'required',
      username: 'required|alpha_numeric|unique:users,username',
      email: 'required|email|unique:users,email',
      firstName: 'required',
      lastName: 'required',
      password: 'required|min:8',
      confirmPassword: 'required|min:8|same:password'
    }
  }
```

By following the examples I found, I tried to like this:

`username: 'required|alpha_numeric|unique:users,username,id,${this.id}',`

But it's still isn't 100%. It doesn't allow me to update the user that already had such `username` or `email`, and doing

`username: 'required|alpha_numeric|unique:users,id,${this.id}',`

It duplicates the data of other users that was suppose to be unique.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use template literals your need to use backticks (`) instead of single/double quotes.

```
username: `required|alpha_numeric|unique:users,username,id,${this.id}`,
```

Documentation: [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

**Note:** `Unique` example in the AdonisJs documentation use backticks ([AdonisJs Validation - Unique](http://adonisjs.com/docs/3.0/validator#unique-))